# Neo4j server timeout

Tags: neo4j, gephi

I am having issues running the Neo4j on my system. Currently I am running it on a Windows machine with Windows 8. It was working great for me, however now when I run the Neo4j.bat in the bin folder it appears to timeout. Below is the error in the logs, I only posted the end of the log because I reached the limit on the post. I did check the setting it refers to and it is already set to true, however I'm not sure what this setting does.

Also I am not entirely clear on the best way to shutdown the server once it is running in this mode. Currently I have been using Ctrl+c on the java process that runs, however I don't think this is correct. What is the best way to do this?

I should mention that I am only really using this server as a development environment. I am setting up my production database on a linux server that is running okay as of now.

> 2014-06-27 19:57:34.679+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:
> System.properties: 2014-06-27 19:57:34.679+0000 INFO
> [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: sun.boot.library.path = C:\Program
> Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\bin 2014-06-27 19:57:34.679+0000 INFO
> [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: org.neo4j.server.properties =
> conf/neo4j-server.properties 2014-06-27 19:57:34.679+0000 INFO
> [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: path.separator = ; 2014-06-27
> 19:57:34.679+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:
> file.encoding.pkg = sun.io 2014-06-27 19:57:34.679+0000 INFO
> [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: user.country = CA 2014-06-27
> 19:57:34.679+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: user.script =
> 2014-06-27 19:57:34.679+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:
> sun.java.launcher = SUN_STANDARD 2014-06-27 19:57:34.679+0000 INFO
> [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: sun.os.patch.level =  2014-06-27
> 19:57:34.679+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: user.dir =
> C:\Users\Phil\Desktop\NEO4J-~1.3 2014-06-27 19:57:34.679+0000 INFO
> [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: user.variant =  2014-06-27
> 19:57:34.679+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:
> log4j.configuration = file:conf/log4j.properties 2014-06-27
> 19:57:34.679+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: sun.jnu.encoding
> = Cp1252 2014-06-27 19:57:34.679+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: sun.management.compiler = HotSpot 64-Bit
> Tiered Compilers 2014-06-27 19:57:34.679+0000 INFO
> [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: user.home = C:\Users\Phil 2014-06-27
> 19:57:34.679+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: user.timezone =
> America/New_York 2014-06-27 19:57:34.679+0000 INFO
> [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: file.encoding = Cp1252 2014-06-27
> 19:57:34.680+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: user.name = Phil
> 2014-06-27 19:57:34.680+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:
> sun.java.command = org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper 2014-06-27
> 19:57:34.680+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:
> sun.arch.data.model = 64 2014-06-27 19:57:34.680+0000 INFO
> [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: user.language = en 2014-06-27
> 19:57:34.680+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: awt.toolkit =
> sun.awt.windows.WToolkit 2014-06-27 19:57:34.680+0000 INFO
> [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: file.separator = \ 2014-06-27
> 19:57:34.680+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:
> sun.io.unicode.encoding = UnicodeLittle 2014-06-27 19:57:34.680+0000
> INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: sun.cpu.endian = little 2014-06-27
> 19:57:34.680+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: sun.desktop =
> windows 2014-06-27 19:57:34.680+0000 INFO
> [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: sun.cpu.isalist = amd64 2014-06-27
> 19:57:34.680+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: Network
> information: 2014-06-27 19:57:34.740+0000 INFO
> [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: Interface Software Loopback Interface 1:
> 2014-06-27 19:57:34.741+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:
> address: 127.0.0.1 2014-06-27 19:57:34.741+0000 INFO
> [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:     address: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 2014-06-27
> 19:57:34.741+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: Interface
> Microsoft Kernel Debug Network Adapter: 2014-06-27 19:57:34.741+0000
> INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: Interface Intel(R) Dual Band
> Wireless-N 7260: 2014-06-27 19:57:34.741+0000 INFO
> [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:     address: 192.168.7.3 2014-06-27
> 19:57:34.741+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:     address:
> fe80:0:0:0:e0c1:1110:ab0d:e5cd%3 2014-06-27 19:57:34.741+0000 INFO
> [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: Interface Teredo Tunneling
> Pseudo-Interface: 2014-06-27 19:57:34.741+0000 INFO
> [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: Interface Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual
> Adapter: 2014-06-27 19:57:34.741+0000 INFO
> [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:     address:
> fe80:0:0:0:b59e:733f:c692:3e78%5 2014-06-27 19:57:34.742+0000 INFO
> [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: Interface Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual
> Adapter #2: 2014-06-27 19:57:34.742+0000 INFO
> [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: Interface Bluetooth Device (Personal
> Area Network): 2014-06-27 19:57:34.742+0000 INFO
> [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:     address:
> fe80:0:0:0:e133:a93a:40ff:bce6%7 2014-06-27 19:57:34.742+0000 INFO
> [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: Interface Bluetooth Device (RFCOMM
> Protocol TDI): 2014-06-27 19:57:34.742+0000 INFO
> [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: Interface Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #4:
> 2014-06-27 19:57:34.742+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:
> address: fe80:0:0:0:0:5efe:c0a8:3801%9 2014-06-27 19:57:34.742+0000
> INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: Interface Intel(R) Dual Band
> Wireless-N 7260 - VirtualBox Bridged Networking Driver Miniport:
> 2014-06-27 19:57:34.742+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:
> Interface VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter: 2014-06-27
> 19:57:34.742+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:     address:
> 192.168.56.1 2014-06-27 19:57:34.742+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:     address:
> fe80:0:0:0:e570:3571:e120:df83%11 2014-06-27 19:57:34.743+0000 INFO
> [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: Interface Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3:
> 2014-06-27 19:57:34.743+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:
> address: fe80:0:0:0:0:5efe:c0a8:703%12 2014-06-27 19:57:34.743+0000
> INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: Interface Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
>
> ## 7: 2014-06-27 19:57:34.743+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: Interface Microsoft ISATAP Adapter: 2014-06-27 19:57:34.743+0000 INFO
>
> [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: Interface Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2:
> 2014-06-27 19:57:34.743+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:
> Interface Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #5: 2014-06-27 19:57:34.743+0000
> INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: Interface VirtualBox Host-Only
> Ethernet Adapter-WFP Native MAC Layer LightWeight Filter-0000:
> 2014-06-27 19:57:34.743+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:
> Interface VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter-QoS Packet
> Scheduler-0000: 2014-06-27 19:57:34.743+0000 INFO
> [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: Interface VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet
> Adapter-WFP 802.3 MAC Layer LightWeight Filter-0000: 2014-06-27
> 19:57:34.743+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: Interface
> Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-N 7260-WFP Native MAC Layer LightWeight
> Filter-0000: 2014-06-27 19:57:34.744+0000 INFO
> [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: Interface Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-N
> 7260-Virtual WiFi Filter Driver-0000: 2014-06-27 19:57:34.744+0000
> INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: Interface Intel(R) Dual Band
> Wireless-N 7260-Native WiFi Filter Driver-0000: 2014-06-27
> 19:57:34.744+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: Interface
> Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-N 7260 - VirtualBox Bridged Networking
> Driver Miniport-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000: 2014-06-27
> 19:57:34.744+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: Interface
> Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-N 7260 - VirtualBox Bridged Networking
> Driver Miniport-WFP 802.3 MAC Layer LightWeight Filter-0000:
> 2014-06-27 19:57:34.744+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:
> Interface Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter-WFP Native MAC Layer
> LightWeight Filter-0000: 2014-06-27 19:57:34.744+0000 INFO
> [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: Interface Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual
> Adapter-Native WiFi Filter Driver-0000: 2014-06-27 19:57:34.744+0000
> INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: Interface Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct
> Virtual Adapter-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000: 2014-06-27
> 19:57:34.744+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: Interface
> Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter-WFP 802.3 MAC Layer LightWeight
> Filter-0000: 2014-06-27 19:57:34.744+0000 INFO
> [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: --- INITIALIZED diagnostics END ---
> 2014-06-27 19:57:34.881+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: ---
> STOPPING diagnostics START --- 2014-06-27 19:57:34.881+0000 INFO
> [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: --- STOPPING diagnostics END ---
> 2014-06-27 19:57:34.882+0000 ERROR [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]:
> Startup failed: Component
> 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager@3aefb8cf' was
> successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached
> cause exception.: Component
> 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource@5a232b4c' was
> successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached
> cause exception.: Failed to start Neo4j with an older data store
> version. To enable automatic upgrade, please set configuration
> parameter "allow_store_upgrade=true" 2014-06-27 19:57:34.882+0000 INFO
> [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: Shutdown started

Comment: Looks like you're trying to start up a newer version of Neo4j than what the original data store was created in.  Do you know the respective versions?

Comment: Hm, well I am only using one version which is 2.0.3. The data that I have was added to this version and I was up until very recently able to start the server.

Comment: Has anything else changed? The error message you're getting is pretty specific about trying to start a version of Neo4j with data that was from an earlier Neo4j version.

Comment: No nothing else has changed that I can think of. Any ideas how to approach this?

Comment: I just remembered something that might be relevant. Between this working and not working I did use Gephi, with the Neo4j plugin to load this data and view it. Could this be the cause?

Comment: It's possible.  I'm not 100% familiar with Gephi, but, if it's using a different version of the Neo4j libs and attempted to transform the data, it could be the cause.  Is there any way you can re-import the data into a fresh Neo4j installation and try again? If anyone here is more familiar with Gephi, perhaps they could weigh in.

Comment: Yea I have all of the cypher scripts used to create the data so I can easily do it again. Just always like to know why things are breaking before I fix them. Just seems odd because I did not know that Gephi actually saved anything to the graph.db, especially because I did not even save my Gephi project.

Comment: I hear you; and I'm not sure that's the actual cause, but, if that's the only thing that changed in between, then it's the most likely culprit.

Comment: You could recreate the database, make a copy of it, load the copy in Gephi and search logs for items pertaining to automatic data store upgrades. If the Gephi Neo4j drivers alter the store that will likely be logged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Gephi Neo4j Plugin was updated to 2.1.2 and so it will update your store when it opens it.

So either use Gephi only on a copy of your store, or also upgrade your sever to 2.1.2